# How to shorten the sentence with parallel words?

Tags: academic-writing

Today I want to write a sentence with the full version is:

"**We use the same set of control variables as in our main regression that is controlling for firm-fixed effects and industry*year fixed effect and controlling for firm-level covariates and country-level covariates**"

What I shorten is as below:

"**We use  the same set of control variables as in our main regression that is controlling for firm and country-level covariates and controlling for firm and year*industry fixed effect**"

I am not sure whether it is correct and is there any better way to shorten or make it simpler?

I think of
"**We use the same set of variables to control for firm and country-level covariates and for firm and year*industry fixed effects as we used in our main regression**" but it is still not that smooth in writing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you refer back to the main regression? For example:

> We use the same set of control variables as in our main regression (Section 1).

If not, I'd focus on breaking the sentence into parts, so the reader can take in a few words at a time. For instance, with a second sentence, and a comma to separate the two kinds of controls:

> We use the same set of control variables as in our main regression. These control for firm and country-level covariates, and for firm and year*industry fixed effect.